# Disable User from Amazon Cognito User pool using API

Tags: amazon-cognito

How can I disable the User from Amazon Cognito User Pool using API ?

I tried to check the API from Amazon and couldn't find one.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the delete_identity_pool?

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific command for disabling user, please see API reference - [API_AdminDisableUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDisableUser.html)

Comment: But if you check AdminEnableUser API, it does below operation.
Enables the specified user as an administrator. Works on any user. It means AdminDisableUser API does reverse of it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is supported here, https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin#admin-queries-api